# Laravel, Sending API routes back to server

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

So I've got a project which is React on the FE and Laravel BE. 99% of all routes are handled through React router, which is fine in the wep.php i've got the following where sends are requests to be handled by React

```
//routes/web.php

Route::get('/{path?}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\ReactController@show',
    'as' => 'react',
    'where' => ['path' => '.*'],
]);
```

The problem comes as we're been asked to implement a wordpress integration which sits inside a sub folder `/blogadmin`

The problem I'm having is that when I try to hit an endpoint on the wordpress api (using wither graphql or the rest api) e.g. `www.mydomain.com/blogadmin/graphql` or `www.mydomain.com/blogadmin/wp-json/wp/v2` the routing is passed to laravel and then back to React.

How can I make the word press endpoints accessible?

I've tried adding `Route::get('/blogadmin/graphql');` to `web.php` as I thought that intercept the request, but no luck!

Comment: `Route::get('/blogadmin/graphql');` has to be **before** `Route::get('/{path?}', ...)` in `web.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was looking at this the wrong way, it's a simple entry in `.htaccess`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogadmin`

directly before

`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

fixed the problem